# Python Pandas IF ELSE

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Would appreciate any help on this, trying to do my first Pandas IF ELSE statement, but I'm struggling with the syntax...

```
if g['Operator'] == 100151:    
    g['floor']=g['y'].mean() 
elif g['Operator'] == 20137: 
    g['floor']=g['y'].mean() 
elif g['Operator'] == 152: 
    g['floor']=g['y'].mean() 
else: 
    g['floor']=g['y'].mean()/2
```

Thanks
Gav

Comment: Do you want the mean of 'y' within the operator group? Or just assign overall mean of 'y' if g['Operator'] matches one of the three provided values? It's hard to tell from your question as you haven't provided any sample data or expected output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, the second one, I need to test the value of the 'Operator' and then if it matches 100151, 20137, or 152 then assign to 'floor' the mean value of 'y', for the rest I want a default else of the mean divided by 2  Hope that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tackle it like this:

```
import numpy as np
g['floor'] = np.where(g['Operator'].isin([100151, 20137, 152]), g['y'].mean(), g['y'].mean() / 2)
```

Check the docs for [where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (basically a vectorized if-else), and [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)